# Matplotlib mpl_connect not working when placed in subroutine called by Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with the Draggable Rectangles example provided in the interactive `matplotlib` example online: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise. I've modified it a bit for my usage: in addition to being draggable, each rectangle drawn should also flip color when `on_release` is triggered.

When I put this all in the same Jupyter cell, it runs as expected:

```
%matplotlib widget

class DraggableRectangle:
    def __init__(self, coords, width, height, color, id_val, ax):
        rect = Rectangle(coords, width, height, color=color)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        self.rect = rect
        self.id_val = id_val
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        """Connect to all the events we need."""
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        """Check whether mouse is over us; if so, store some data."""
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes:
            return
        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains:
            return
        print('event contains', self.rect.xy)
        self.press = self.rect.xy, (event.xdata, event.ydata), self.id_val

    def on_motion(self, event):
        """Move the rectangle if the mouse is over us."""
        if self.press is None or event.inaxes != self.rect.axes:
            return

        (x0, y0), (xpress, ypress), _ = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        print(f'x0={x0}, xpress={xpress}, event.xdata={event.xdata}, '
              f'dx={dx}, x0+dx={x0+dx}')
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        """Clear button press information."""
        print("Releasing the rectangle")
        if self.id_val == self.press[2]:
            if self.rect.get_facecolor() == (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0):
                self.rect.set_color((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
            else:
                self.rect.set_color((0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0))

        self.press = None
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def disconnect(self):
        """Disconnect all callbacks."""
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        
drs = []
id_val = 1
for i in np.arange(0, 250, 50):
    for j in np.arange(0, 150, 50):
        dr = DraggableRectangle((100 + i, 100 + j), 25, 25, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), id_val, ax)
        dr.connect()
        drs.append(dr)
        id_val += 1

plt.xlim([0, 1000])
plt.ylim([0, 1000])
```

However, let's say I refactor the code as such:

rectangle.py

```
# assume all imports have been made
class DraggableRectangle:
    def __init__(self, coords, width, height, color, id_val, ax):
        rect = Rectangle(coords, width, height, color=color)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        self.rect = rect
        self.id_val = id_val
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        """Connect to all the events we need."""
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        """Check whether mouse is over us; if so, store some data."""
        if event.inaxes != self.rect.axes:
            return
        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains:
            return
        print('event contains', self.rect.xy)
        self.press = self.rect.xy, (event.xdata, event.ydata), self.id_val

    def on_motion(self, event):
        """Move the rectangle if the mouse is over us."""
        if self.press is None or event.inaxes != self.rect.axes:
            return

        (x0, y0), (xpress, ypress), _ = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        print(f'x0={x0}, xpress={xpress}, event.xdata={event.xdata}, '
              f'dx={dx}, x0+dx={x0+dx}')
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        """Clear button press information."""
        print("Releasing the rectangle")
        if self.id_val == self.press[2]:
            if self.rect.get_facecolor() == (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0):
                self.rect.set_color((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
            else:
                self.rect.set_color((0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0))

        self.press = None
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def disconnect(self):
        """Disconnect all callbacks."""
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

def plot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        
    drs = []
    id_val = 1
    for i in np.arange(0, 250, 50):
        for j in np.arange(0, 150, 50):
            dr = DraggableRectangle((100 + i, 100 + j), 25, 25, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), id_val, ax)
            dr.connect()
            drs.append(dr)
            id_val += 1

    plt.xlim([0, 1000])
    plt.ylim([0, 1000])
```

Jupyter cell:

```
%matplotlib widget
import rectangle
rectangle.plot()
```

The refactored version displays the rectangles but doesn't add any of the desired interactive features.

Would appreciate any pointers in this regard. Would I have to implement `mpl_connect` directly inside Jupyter or is there a way I can refactor my code so it can add the interactivity?

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks are stored as weak references and stop functioning when the containing object is garbage collected. All DraggableRectangle objects are lost when you exit the plot function. Return drs and hold it in a variable.

[https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#:~:text=The%20canvas%20retains%20only,functions%20used%20as%20callbacks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#:%7E:text=The%20canvas%20retains%20only,functions%20used%20as%20callbacks).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31779502)